# Helm's buffers persist even after an action has been executed in them

Tags: helm

Helm's buffers remain active even after an action has been executed in them.

To illustrate this point, open a new Emacs session, and execute `C-x C-b` to view a list of all active buffers. The list consists of three items: `*GNU Emacs*`, `*scratch*` and `*Messages*`.

[image: Active buffers before Helm]

Now execute `M-x helm-mini`, and select the first item on the list, namely `*scratch*`.
[image: helm-mini]

Finally, execute `C-x C-b` again. You can see that in addition to the original three buffers, `*Completions*` as well as `*helm-mini*` are also on the list.

[image: Active buffers after Helm]

This behavior is undesirable, as it results in unnecessary buffer clutter.

Is this how Helm's buffers are supposed to behave? Is there a way to force them to truly close once an action has been chosen in them?

Comment: Everything in Emacs creates buffers and keeps them around. Helm is no exception to this. There is even an `#emacs` factoid famously saying "Buffer economy is false economy".

Comment: @wasamasa: Alright, so I have a follow up question. Why doesn't the `helm` version of `C-x C-b` (= the `ibuffer` command), namely `C-x c C-x C-b` (= the `helm-buffers-list` command), list the active `helm` buffers?

Comment: It's because it doesn't make sense to switch to them, so they're not offered in its candidate list.

Comment: @wasamasa: This begs the question why are they offered in `ibuffer`'s candidate list, then?

Comment: It's natural that a helm command knows about uninteresting helm buffers, the same cannot be said about a part of Emacs.